# Sort data in jQuery by specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, attributes

I'm trying to sort data in jQuery by a specific attribute like following:

```
<table id="tableSellers" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
      <th class="column-title"><h4><i class="fa fa-user" style="text-align:center"></i> <span>Username</span></h4> </th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="column-title"> <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks salesClick" aria-hidden="true"></span></h4></th>
      <th class="column-title"><h4><i class="fa fa-star feedbackClick"></i></h4></th>      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="testWrapper">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.rezultati)
    {
      <tr class="test" sale=@item.SaleNumber feedback=@item.Feedback>
        <td>
          <a href="http://ebay.com/usr/@item.StoreName" target="_blank">@item.StoreName</a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" value="@item.StoreName" data-original-title="Analyze competitor">
              <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>
            @item.SaleNumber
          </b>
        </td>
        <td><b>@item.Feedback</b></td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the code I'm currently using to sort the data, but it doesn't works as I want it to:

```
$(".feedbackClick").click(function () {
  var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');
  $wrapper.find('.test').sort(function (a, b) {
     return +a.feedback - +b.feedback;
  })
  .appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

This just sorts 1 item in the whole table (or something, I'm not really sure?)

Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: Here is the rendered tr tag:

```
<table id="tableSellers" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
      <th class="column-title">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-user" style="text-align:center"></i> <span>Username</span></h4> </th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="column-title">
        <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks salesClick" aria-hidden="true"></span></h4></th>
      <th class="column-title">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-star feedbackClick"></i></h4></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="testWrapper">
    <tr class="test" sale="0" feedback="349">
      <td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/kansascitykittygirl" target="_blank">kansascitykittygirl</a></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" value="kansascitykittygirl" data-original-title="Analyze competitor"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i></button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>0</b>
      </td>
      <td><b>349</b></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="test" sale="10" feedback="14250">
      <td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/fancaveidaho" target="_blank">fancaveidaho</a></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" value="fancaveidaho" data-original-title="Analyze competitor"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i></button>
      </td>
      <td><b>10</b></td>
      <td><b>14250</b></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: jQuery does not have a `.sort()` method. What are `a.feedback`, `b.feedback` expected to represent? What is expected result? Can you include rendered `html` at Question?

Comment: you can't run jQuery or javaScript in your HTML.  You need to put that inside a <script tag>.  Add an event handler on the sort button to call the sort function.  Within the sort function re-load your select box

Comment: @Claus It's already handled in script tag I just forgot to add it here sry..

Comment: @guest271314 Expected result is to have tr's inside the table sorted from bigger to lower feedback value..

Comment: `a.feedback`, `b.feedback` are text of last `td` element within `tr` element?

Comment: @guest271314 yes that's correct, i just put them in TR as attribute sale=@item.SaleNumber feedback=@item.Feedback so that I can sort them

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 I included the rendered HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `a.feedback` and `b.feedback` are not getting `feedback` attribute's value. You can use `$(a).attr('feedback')` and `$(b).attr('feedback')` instead like following.

```js
$(".feedbackClick").click(function() {
    var $wrapper = $('.testWrapper');

    $wrapper.find('.test').sort(function(a, b) {
        return +$(b).attr('feedback') - +$(a).attr('feedback');
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableSellers" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
      <th class="column-title">
        Title
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="testWrapper">
    <tr class="test" feedback="1">
      <td>1111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test" feedback="3">
      <td>3333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test" feedback="2">
      <td>2222</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="feedbackClick">Sort</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Azim this sorts the items in a reversed order (from smaller to higher - not higher to smaller)

Comment: if I wanna sort out the items now by sales, do I do the same procedure like this one ?

Comment: Yes. Like this one. @User987